# Table with two links - table row clickable - jQuery

Tags: jquery, hyperlink, html-table, row, href

I've a table containing 2 links,

- if I click the 'button' the link should target 'page1'
- if I click the entire row the should target 'page2'

I'm currently stuck with the jQuery Javascript - can someone give me an advice?

HTML & JQuery / JS

```
<tr>
  <td><a href="page2.html" class="info"><img src="img/img.png" alt="image" class="tlogo"/></a></td>
  <td>Some Text</td>
  <td><a href="page1.html" class="tbutton">Go to page1</a></td>
</tr>

    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('#myTable tr').click(function() {
            var href = $(this).find("a").attr("href");
            if(href) {
                window.location = href;
            }
        });
    });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you click on the button, the row click will be fired too. The way to stop that is to use `event.stopPropagation();`

That will cancel any events that will fire after that, so if you put that in the button click event, the row click event will not fire.

Comment: ++ 1 `event.stopPropogation` indeed see my post demo below. `:)`

Answer (score 2):

Try something like:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#myTable a').click(function(e){
        window.location = $(e.currentTarget).attr('href');
        e.stopPropagation();
    });

    /* Assuming that the link you want to go to on clicking the row is in the first td */

    $('#myTable tr').click(function(e) {
        window.location = $('#myTable tr a',e.currentTarget).attr('href');
        e.stopPropagation();
    });
});
```

Comment: Hiya few suggestions note: use `event.stopPropogation` and it will be worth doing the correct mapping of like `$('#id tr td a`) just few note `:)` +1 anyways :P

Answer (score 0):

You can do one thing :-

```
<tr>
  <td><a href="page2.html" class="info"><img src="img/img.png" alt="image" class="tlogo"/></a></td>
  <td>Some Text</td>
  <td><a href="page1.html" class="tbutton">Go to page1</a></td>
</tr>

$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.tbutton').click(function() {            
        window.location.href = page1.html;
    });
 $('"#mytable tr').click(function() {            
            window.location.href = page2.html;
        });
});
```

Hope this is helpful :)

Answer (score 0):

**Working demo** http://jsfiddle.net/5ykup/4/

API: http://api.jquery.com/event.stopPropagation/ it : Prevents the event from bubbling up the DOM tree, preventing any parent handlers from being notified of the event.

Hope this helps,

**code**

```
   $("table tr").click(function(){
       alert("go to page1");        
    });

    $("table tr td a").click(function(event){
        alert("go to PAGE == 2"); 
        event.stopPropagation();
    });
```